# xdvipdfmx typecheck problem

Tags: xdvipdfmx

I have a very simple .tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf{blank.pdf}
\end{document}
```

When I compile this with xelatex (xelatex sample.tex) I get an error:

xdvipdfmx:fatal: typecheck: Invalid object type: -1 7 (line 2167)
No output PDF file written.
Error 1 (driver return code) generating output;

blank.pdf is a simple empty PDF page. "pdfinfo blank.pdf" returns this:

```
Title:
Creator:        Microsoft Word: cgpdftops CUPS filter
Producer:       Acrobat Distiller 9.4.2 (Macintosh)
CreationDate:   Tue Apr 19 11:41:26 2011 Romance Daylight Time
ModDate:        Mon May 13 12:38:48 2019 Romance Daylight Time
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           AcroForm
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595.22 x 842 pts (A4)
Page rot:       0
File size:      14695 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.6
```

I think this has something to do with a recent update to MikTex, as I did not notice this problem before.

I'm lost here. Maybe I should downgrade my Latex installation? How? Any ideas?

Thank you very much

Comment: Does it work with `pdflatex` and/or `lualatex`? Does it work with `\includegraphics` instead of `\includepdf`? Maybe remove the `.pdf` extension in your code? The PDF information shows a form, is there or has there been a form in the document? Does the problem also occur in pdf files without forms? Does it work with a pdf generated with LaTeX?

Comment: Can you make the blank.pdf available somewhere?

Comment: I tried with \includegraphics instead of \includepdf and I get the same error. Using pdflatex or lualatex (instead of xelatex) I get no error. Removing the .pdf extension in the code does not seem to have any impact. The PDF file is just an empty page, no forms included. I left the blank.pdf file available at https://we.tl/t-rkSaMJU2VP

Comment: Using MiKTeX I confirm no build with error : file sample.pdf may not be valid when loading (MacCUPS PDFv1.6) blank.pdf any other (v1.5)pdf here loads fine

Comment: I am pretty sure this worked for me also before updating MiKTex... I think that this is something related to the most recent version.

Comment: I have included other 1.6 created by adobe So It may be down to the way the blank is built by Word try other ways of generating a blank pdf via cups

Comment: Something well weird with that file combination I flattened it using several apps, added a comment to it, Passed it through a repair tool removing all metadata so it reduced down to only a basic 5k changed metadata such as date built title etc etc it is ALWAYS viewable with those changes in a pdf viewer but NEVER imports with XeLaTeX some component buried in there is upsetting XeLaTeX short of adding text and seriously down revving with all object removed by acrobat itself (the only way its contents may be fully reflowed/rebuilt) I'm stumped it needs plain text decoding to find a rogue item

Comment: Your pdf is faulty. preflight reports a missing key `/First`. It is possible that there is a bug in xdvipdfmx or that something changed (there has been updates here) but with a faulty pdf one can't report anything.

Comment: Works in Tex Live (perhaps more tolerant of the flaw) Thus file specific problem with MiKTeX I suggest open an issue there

Comment: Thank you very much for all the pointers. I checked indeed with Acrobat and its preflight options and it reports a problem with the "Report PDF syntax issues". However, the "Analyze and fix" button is disabled (I can only select "Analyze" and see that there is a problem, but no possibility to fix it there). Any ideas about how this can be fixed? I left an example of a faulty PDF, but I have several ones that lead to similar problems. I can see all the PDF files correctly with popular PDF viewers (I tried to save the PDF file again with those viewers but they seem to keep the faulty fragments).

Comment: Not sure if this is specific to MiKTeX only, as I tried also with the latest version of MacTeX and the problem appears also there.

Comment: I was able to get "fixed"pdf outputs by using a resize tool that adds a watermark or commercial printers pre-flight corrector which adds bleed/crop margins, not sure what pdf manipulation tools you have access to e.g. those for tex conversions but if you look to those that "correct" page boundaries that may clear the issue If time critical Why not use pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to include then save for a xelatex run ?

Comment: I am worried that there might be somes side effect, but the solution commented in https://superuser.com/questions/1066419/how-to-use-ghostscript-for-windows-to-repair-damaged-pdf-files seems to work to fix the PDF files. Then, the problem I commented about xelatex disappears.

Comment: My previous solution of fixing the PDF using gswin does not seem to solve all the problems. I tried with an example PDF available at http://www.boa.aragon.es/cgi-bin/EBOA/BRSCGI?CMD=VEROBJ&MLKOB=1072665203030. Acrobat reports no syntax problems with this file, but xelatex complains again and fails. Applying gswin on the PDF does not help here (as opposed to other sample PDF files where preflight actually finds a syntax error). Any idea is greatly appreciated. I'm stuck here despite all the efforts.

Comment: Just to add some additional info, this happens with both the last versions of MikTeX and TeXLive. This is what "xelatex - version" returns in each case: "MiKTeX-XeTeX 2.9.6942 (0.999991) (MiKTeX 2.9.7000 64-bit)" and "XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX)".

Comment: Just revisited and saw your comment Odd that latest Spanish one works for me in win 64bit miktex XeLaTeX same version as you Double check the download was not corrupted file length 162,184 bytes

Comment: I guess you are talking about the PDF file at http://www.boa.aragon.es/cgi-bin/EBOA/BRSCGI?CMD=VEROBJ&MLKOB=1072665203030. If so, yes, the download was correct and I can open it with no problems with a PDF viewer (besides, Acrobat does not detect there any syntax problem). I tried with TeX Live 2018 and it works there but not (in my environment) with Text Live 2019.

Comment: Any idea about why the MWE shown above with the latest version of Latex does not work when replacing blank.pdf with the PDF file located at this URL?:
http://www.boa.aragon.es/cgi-bin/EBOA/BRSCGI?CMD=VEROBJ&MLKOB=1072665203030

The error is the one described in the initial question. This is quite confusing...